How Can I fix the GetJsonDomContent method error in TwinCAT 3?
I have to send Temperature Sensor value and System Time to the server and the server only accepts JSON format.
Now each 10-sec temperature value and the time retrieved from PLC and shown in JSON format by using TwinCAT3.
For adding json header to the request I wrote the following line of code before using the SendJsonDomRequest method:
fbHeader.AddField(sField:='content-type',sValue:='application/json',FALSE);

HttpStatusCode returns 200 but when I want to Parse the server response I face an issue and the result of jsonDoc shows 0
jsonDoc:=fbRequest.GetJsonDomContent(fbJson);

Flags status:

nContentSize = 0 and fbJson = 0
I would appreciate it if anybody could please guide me on how I can fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.
